# How to add a border to TText or TLabel in FireMonkey?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, vcl

I usually code using VCL in C++Builder, but now I'm using FireMonkey for a multi-platform project, and I have some difficulties.

In VCL, it is easy to set a solid rectangular border for `TStaticText` by setting its `BorderStyle` property to `sbsSingle`.

In FireMonkey, there is no `TStaticText` control, instead there is `TText`, but I'm not able to set a solid rectangular border for it.

Also, a `TLabel` with a border should be OK, but even in this case I don't know how to set a border for it.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, there are no text control with borders. However, it is easy to make one, by combining a `TRectangle` and a `TLabel` (or a `TText`).

- Add a `TRectangle` and set its `Stroke` (and `Fill`) properties as you wish.
- Drop a `TText` or `TLabel` on the rectangle and set its properties as needed.

Example:

```
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Fill.Kind = None
    Position.X = 50.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 120.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 181.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 41.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Color = claCrimson
    Stroke.Thickness = 4.000000000000000000
    object Text1: TText
      Align = Client
      Size.Width = 181.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 41.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Text = 'Here'#39's some text'
      TextSettings.Font.Size = 20.000000000000000000
      TextSettings.Font.Style = [fsBold]
      TextSettings.FontColor = claBlue
    end
  end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Tom! This is a good solution for my problem.